# How to make function which return name of key associated with the array in which need to find the value?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a function that can be used to get the name of the key associated with the array in which need to find the value. Currently, the function does not return the name of the array key with the required value. Who could can give a solve for get need result?

```
$Arr = array(
    "A" => array(
        "A1" => array("val"=>001),
        "B1" => array("val"=>002),  
    ),
    "B" => array(
        "A2" => array("val"=>007)
    ),
);

function returnTreeWithNamesArrayToSearch_value($array, $search_value) {

    foreach($array as $k => $v) { 

        if ($v==$search_value) return $k; 

        if(is_array($v)) {

            $tree[]=$k;

            $find = returnTreeWithNamesArrayToSearch_value($v, $search_value);
            if($find) return $tree;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(returnTreeWithNamesArrayToSearch_value($Arr, 007));
```

Result:

```
0 => string 'A' (length=19)
1 => string 'B' (length=5)

---------------------------------------
```

Need result:

```
0 => string 'A' (length=19)
1 => string 'B' (length=5)
2 => string 'A2' (length=5)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired result. If you're looking for value `007`, shouldn't you just get 'A2', or maybe 'B' and 'A2'? Why are you returning A too?

Comment: Need to  get an array with  keys to value by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is adding back in the various levels of keys, to get round this, I always return an array (just the single item is now `[$k]`, and use `array_merge()` to add this output back into the list of keys.

The nearest I can get with your current structure is...

```
function returnTreeWithNamesArrayToSearch_value($array, $search_value){
    $tree = [];
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if($v==$search_value) 
            return [$k];
        if(is_array($v)){
            $find = returnTreeWithNamesArrayToSearch_value($v, $search_value);
            if($find)   {
                return array_merge([$k], $find);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

which gives...

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "B"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "A2"
  [2] =>
  string(3) "val"
}
```